# Make glossaries render see references to use name attribute instead of text

Tags: glossaries

When using the `see` attribute for a glossary entry, `glossaries` seems to use the `text` attribute to create the *see also ...* text in the glossary. How can I change this to use the `name` attribute instead?

According to the [glossaries documentation](http://mirror.easyname.at/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#sec:newglosentry) the `name` attribute would be the correct one to show anyway:

**name** The name of the entry (as it will appear in the glossary). If this
key is omitted and the parent key is supplied, this value will be
the same as the parent’s name.

**text** How this entry will appear in the document text when using
`\gls` (or one of its upper case variants). If this field is omitted,
the value of the name key is used.

Since the *see also ...* text is shown within the glossary, `name` should be used instead of `text`.

Comment: `glossaries` certainly seems to use the `name` attribute.  In my documents, at least, and I've done nothing special to make it so.  Might you have accidentally changed something to cause different behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Taken from the *empsample-crossref.tex* example from `glossaries`:

```
\renewcommand{\glsseeitemformat}[1]{\glsentryname{#1}}
```